# What does this ground cable connect to?

Tags: jeep, wrangler, ground, wire

so i was filming for youtube and came across this random ground wire that wasn't bolted to anything, it's on a '99 jeep wrangler TJ, any of y'all know where this goes?

[image: Random ground wire]
[image: Random Ground wire #2]

Comment: What is the other end of the ground strap attached to?

Comment: onto the body, i think it's supposed to be for somewhere on the engine, but if I'm not mistaken there's already another wire there

Comment: You could have multiple ground straps from engine to the body. You pretty much can never have enough ground straps. I'd look on the head studs to see if there is one which has a stud running out the end of it within reach of where the strap can go to. The strap should have lots of slack in it where ever it should go, so don't stretch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should connect to the hood/bonnet.

I got this photo from [here](https://wranglertjforum.com/threads/ground-strap-question.1966/)

I guessed it was from the hood and did a google search "jeep wrangler hood earth strap"

You can see the bolt hole in your photo.

Sometimes bad electrical connections on things like hinges can increase radio noise.  The earth strap electrically bypasses the hinge.

[image]

Comment: alright, I'll check it out when I get home, I'm currently at school

Comment: Yup, and pretty easy to see in the photos where it needs to go. Well done, Howie.

Comment: @HandyHowie the hole that you had found, is it supposed to be threaded? because for me, it's not

Comment: I don’t know.  I just found the photo in a google search.  It looks like it should be easy enough to put a nut behind the hole.

Comment: Does your hood/bonnet look like it has been replaced?  Maybe it is not the original and that is why the strap has not been connected.